# Extremely simple python password generator

Tags: python

I tried to make a password generator and at first it works as intended, generating a password with lowercase, uppercase and special characters but I can only generate passwords of up to 19 characters any more and the script sends an error about a string being too big or something.

```
import random

generator = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm0123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM.!?*"
generatorLength = len(generator)

def Generator():
    acc = 0
    password = ''
    length = int(input("How long?\n"))
    if length < 6:
        print("Can't be less than 6\n")
        Generator()
    while acc < length:
        password += generator[random.randint(0, generatorLength)]
        acc += 1
    print("Password:", password)


Generator()
```

Comment: Hello, this question is off-topic, since the code is not working as intended; I suggest that you read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) `Code Review aims to help improve working code. If you are trying to figure out why your program crashes or produces a wrong result, ask on Stack Overflow instead. Code Review is also not the place to ask for implementing new features.`

Comment: `and the script sends an error about a string being too big or something` a) *which* `script sends an error`? b) `or something` when asking an appropriate audience, be sure to quote any error messages verbatim.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because string indexes start on 0 rather than 1, your upper limit for the random interger should be the length of generator minus one. That is, the last character on your generator string is given by generator[generatorLength - 1].

Comment: `random.randrange`

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions with code that doesn't work.